# Setup openvpn client on centos 6.4

Tags: openvpn, centos6.4

Attempting to join a new CentOS 6.4 client to an existing OpenVPN network. Running **service openvpn start** gives the error:

```
Options error: In [CMD-LINE]:1: Error opening configuration file: client.conf
Use --help for more information
```

If I use

```
bash -vx service openvpn start
```

the service starts successfully.

If I run the cmd-line from the `init.d` script the service starts successfully.

It just doesn't want to start like it needs to if this process is going to work at reboot.

I am using `SELinux` in *enforcing* mode but I'm not seeing any messages in `/var/log/secure` or `/var/log/messages` indicating that `SELinux` is getting involved.

Suggestions?

Comment: Try `ausearch -m avc -ts today`, and the log you need to watch is `/var/log/audit/audit.log`.

Comment: It reports "<no matches>"

Comment: then, either SELinux is not involved, or the AVC denials are in `dontaudit` mode. Can you please add the output of `ls -lrtZ /path/to/client.conf`?

Comment: -rw-rw-r--. root root unconfined_u:object_r:user_tmp_t:s0 /etc/openvpn/client.conf

Comment: now check if that is the proper context: `matchpathcon /etc/openvpn/client.conf` and restore it if it doesn't: `restorecon -v /etc/openvpn/client.conf`

Comment: Interesting. Did the `restorecon` and it set values. Running `service openvpn start` shows that it's reading the config file now. It reports `cannot load certificate file...`. Is this the same process to update / repair?

Comment: I don't know. Go check it out. Use the same commands (with the appropriate paths, of course)

Comment: To avoid me becoming a 'help vampire' please summarize your suggestions in an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to be the security context of some files.

The steps you need to take are:

1. check if trying to start the service generates AVC denials

   ```
   # ausearch -m avc -ts today
   ```

   it could be the case that there were no output. You could try to [disable `dontaudit` rules temporarily](https://access.redhat.com/site/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Security-Enhanced_Linux/sect-Security-Enhanced_Linux-Fixing_Problems-Possible_Causes_of_Silent_Denials.html)

   ```
   # semodule -DB
   ```
2. check the permissions and security labels of the affected files and/or directories

   ```
   # ls -lrtZ /path/to/file
   # ls -lrtdZ /path/to/dir
   ```
3. query the current policy to see what is the expected security label

   ```
   # matchpathcon /path/to/file
   # matchpathcon /path/to/dir
   ```
4. if the current security label and the expected security label don't match, restore it. Note that you can restore directories recursively

   ```
   # restorecon -v /path/lo/file
   # restorecon -v -R /path/to/dir
   ```
5. try again to start the service and repeat the steps if necessary

Answer (score 1):

The SELinux contexts on your OpenVPN configuration and certificate files are incorrect. Most likely this is because you moved them into place instead of copied them.

To resolve the issue, restore their default security contexts (this is safe to do even if they already have the right security context). This command will recursively fix the security contexts on `/etc/openvpn` and every file and directory under it.

```
restorecon -r -v /etc/openvpn
```